# A string literal starts with single quote and ends with triple quote, how it is valid?

Tags: python

Q1). How it is valid, if string starts with single quote and ends with triple quote?

Q2). Why third and fourth print statement are invalid if second one is valid?

```
print('This is "python" programming') #valid
print('This is "python" programming''') #valid
print(''This is "python" programming''') #Invalid
print('''This is "python" programming') #Invalid
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python you can [concatenate strings by putting them one next to other](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/string-catenation.html).

E.g.:  `"a" "b"`, or even on multiple lines:

```
re.compile("[A-Za-z_]"       # letter or underscore
           "[A-Za-z0-9_]*"   # letter, digit or underscore
          )
```

So `'This is "python" programming'''` is the concatenation of `'This is "python" programming'` and `''`.

The triple quote (`'''` or `"""`) is another type of quote for having a string span over multiple lines.

From python manual:

> String literals can span multiple lines. One way is using triple-quotes: `"""..."""` or `'''...'''`. End of lines are automatically included in the string, but it’s possible to prevent this by adding a \ at the end of the line.

Third example is sintactically invalid, because it's the empty string followed by identifiers that do not make sense to python.

Last example is invalid because it begins with triple quotes, but does not close the triple quotes.